# How to create SSIS script task to remove the CR LF from a flat file

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012, flat-file

We have an SSIS job that takes data from a database and outputs it to a csv file and saves it to a file share. The last line in the csv we produce is a blank row and the consumers of this file want it removed. I need to figure out how, after we write the file to the directory, to modify the file and remove that last blank row. I believe you can do this in a script task but everything I have tried has failed, both VB and C#. Has anyone figured out how to do something like this?

Comment: I would look into the generation piece that creates an empty line at the end of the file and fix that so it doesnt create the empty line

Comment: Do you absolutely need to remove the blank row after the file has been saved? It would be easier to do that before.

Comment: I have followed suggestions on how to prevent the blank row before writing the file and none of those have worked for me. Because each row needs to have a line break, you always end up with one blank row in the file you save.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works as I am shooting from the hip:

This should remove the last carriage return and line feed.

C#

```
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText([filePath]); 
s=s.Substring(1,s.Length-2); //CRLF
System.IO.File.WriteAllText([filePath],s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Conditional Split Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/conditional-split-transformation?view=sql-server-2017) in between source and destination on a Data Flow pipeline to remove empty rows.

[image]

In the Split Transformation Editor specify a boolean expression with a Condition like

```
LEN([Col 1]) > 0 && LEN([Col 2]) > 0 ...
```

[image]

Bonus: If there is also bad data in the output file you may want to filter on a different length (as shown in the screenshot): [Ref](http://www.geekswithblogs.net/Compudicted/archive/2011/02/15/ssis-technique-to-removeskip-trailer-andor-bad-data-row-in.aspx).

---

If this still does not work I suggest to try it with a C# script task along that lines:

```
try
{
    string input = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path");
    string output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, @"^\s+$[\r\n]*", "", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("path", output);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Log..
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```

If you also want to remove the very last line-break use this pattern with the code above instead: `@"^\s+$[\r\n]*|[\r\n]$"`

Comment: This was one of the solutions I already tried. When you set the target destination file you are right back to where you started, because the CR LF defined in the output. So you still get the blank row in the output file.

Comment: Have you also tried a different length like `LEN([Col 1]) > 2`

Comment: Yes, the issue isn't the split but the saving of the file to a flat file destination, there you will always end up with the trailing empty row. I will take a look at your script task, thanks for your help on this.

Comment: @user7593937 I see. I have updated the suggested pattern.